# Return component to original state or force re-render after using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Good evening,

I have a component that changes based on the state of a modal on which it resides.  I am attempting to return the component to its original state by returning the modal's state to its prior setting but it is not working.  I know the state is changing back because the console tells me so but the notification component is not changing back to null when the state returns to default.  How do I force the notification component to revert to null when the component's state changes?

My modal is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

import './emailModal.css';

class emailModal extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sent: false,
        error: false
    }

    //these two methods are my attempt to reset the component after it changes
    sentTimeoutMethod = () => {
        setTimeout(this.setState({ sent: false }), 500);
        setTimeout(this.props.cancelled, 700);
    }

    errorTimeoutMethod = () => {
        setTimeout(this.setState({ error: false }), 1800);
        setTimeout(this.props.cancelled, 2000);
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        emailjs.sendForm('default_service', 'template_Fo3IEDvY', e.target,'user_m4BBDdGwESsTJhnMIKqFP')
        .then((result) => {
            this.sentTimeoutMethod();
            this.setState({ sent: true });
        }).catch(
            (error) => {
                this.errorTimeoutMethod();
                this.setState({ error: true });
            });
};

render() {

    let buttons = (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Button className="buttonSize send mr-1"
                size="lg"
                outline="true"
                type="submit">
                <i className="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </Button>
            <Button className="buttonSize cancel mr-1"
                size="lg"
                variant="secondary"
                onClick={this.props.cancelled}>
                <i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );

    let notification;

    if (this.state.sent) {
        notification = <p className="grey-text">Sent!</p>
    } else if (this.state.error) {
        notification = <p className="grey-text">Found and error: please let me know on Github or LinkedIn</p>
    } else {
        notification = null;
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Modal.Dialog
                className="emailModal"
                style={{
                    transform: this.props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                    opacity: this.props.show ? '1' : '0'
                }}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Send me an email</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <form id="emailFormId"
                        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        className="emailForm"
                        method="post"
                    >
                        <label
                            htmlFor="formName"
                            className="grey-text"
                        >
                            Your name
                    </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="formName"
                            name="contactName"
                            className="form-control"
                            required
                        />
                        <br />
                        <label
                            htmlFor="formEmail"
                            className="grey-text">
                            Your email
                    </label>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            id="formEmail"
                            name="contactEmail"
                            className="form-control"
                            required
                        />
                        <br />
                        <label
                            htmlFor="formMessage"
                            className="grey-text">
                            I look forward to hearing from you
                    </label>
                        <textarea type="text"
                            id="formMessage" name="contactMessage"
                            className="form-control"
                            rows="4"
                            required
                        />
                        <div className="text-center mt-4">
                            {buttons}
                            {notification}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal.Dialog>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
};

export default emailModal;
```

this.props.cancelled just sets show=false for the modal component.  If more code is required to answer my question please let me know.

Here is a stripped down version of the app that demonstrates the issue.  You may have to rename a few raw files with a .js extension... for some reason my javascript sometimes won't keep their .js.
https://2qh47.csb.app/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create example of your project in online ide?

Comment: I'm new enough to this platform that I don't know how best to do that.  It seems like codepen would be a bad idea.  Is there one associated with stack overflow that you would recommend?

Comment: try this one https://codesandbox.io. In the meantime I will try to past your code in laptop and figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentTimeoutMethod = () => {
let self = this;
setTimeout(self.setState({ sent: false }), 500); 
setTimeout(self.props.cancelled, 700); }
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to have fixed the issue